# How to configure django logging for production under gunicorn server?

Tags: django, logging, gunicorn

I have this logging configuration set up:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': sys.stdout,
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'gunicorn.errors': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

It seems to have no effect at all. When the flag `DEBUG` is set to `True` then I can see some errors in the console. When however it's set to `False`, I cannot. So how to log the errors to the console despite `DEBUG` flag being set one way or the other?

Comment: what django version you using?

Comment: Django Version is 1.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In django `1.9` the [default logging configuration has been changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#changes-to-the-default-logging-configuration):

> Changes to the default logging configuration¶
>
> To make it easier to write custom logging configurations, Django’s
>   default logging configuration no longer defines ‘django.request’ and
>   ‘django.security’ loggers. Instead, it defines a single ‘django’
>   logger, filtered at the INFO level, with two handlers:
>
> ‘console’: filtered at the INFO level and only active if DEBUG=True.
>   ‘mail_admins’: filtered at the ERROR level and only active if
>   DEBUG=False. If you aren’t overriding Django’s default logging, you
>   should see minimal changes in behavior, but you might see some new
>   logging to the runserver console, for example.
>
> If you are overriding Django’s default logging, you should check to
>   see how your configuration merges with the new defaults.

So what you need to do is simply override the default config, add this to your `loggers`:

```
'django':{
    'level': 'INFO',
    'handlers': ['console'],
    'propagate': True,
}
```

Logging to console wont depend on `DEBUG` now.

Hope this helps!

Comment: also i think you can remove `gunicorn.error` and the `disable_existing_loggers`, unless you have additional config that needs them

Comment: I actually replaced the gunicorn.error with the contents you provided because it wasn't doing anything.

Comment: It has been changed back to `django.request` and `django.server` in Django 1.11. https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.7/django/utils/log.py

Comment: thanks @akshar, weird, there's no reference to this on the 1.11 release notes ..., i ll see how to add this to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `--capture-output` and `--enable-stdio-inheritance` with gunicorn

```
/home/ubuntu/inside-env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile access.log --error-logfile error.log --capture-output --enable-stdio-inheritance --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/path-to-project/webapp.sock project.wsgi:application
```

and then in your views,

```
import logging 
logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')
logging.info('...something...')
```